# Do char arrays initialized this way have null terminators automatically added?

Tags: c++, string, memory, char

Does a char array initialized like so:

```
char foo[] = {0x31, 0x32, 0x33}; //123
```

get a null terminator added to the end of it so the memory data at `foo` would look something like 0x31323300? Or does this simply write 0x313233 to memory?
Also, is foo treated like a string literal by the compiler regardless of this method of initialization?

Comment: No they don't have a null terminator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, if you don't specify a size of the array and do not use a string-literal as initializer, the size and contents of the array will be exactly matching the initializers you have.

In your case the array `foo` will be exactly three `char` elements containing (in order) `0x31`, `0x32` and `0x33`.

If you use a string-literal as initializer, then the array will include the terminator. And if you specify a size larger than the number of initializers (like e.g. `char foo[4]` in your example with three initializers) then the remaining elements will be zero-initialized (which is equal to the string terminator).

If you use a string literal as initializer, but a size *smaller* than the string length (including the null-terminator) then the compiler will complain. You *must* have a size at least the same length as the string (including null-terminator).

Comment: You got to the answer first so I will accept your answer when the option becomes available to me.

Answer (score 3):

`foo` is just a plain old `char` array with three elements, and no null-terminator. The only place the compiler would "magically" add a null terminator is when you use a string literal, i.e., a string denoted by double quotes (`"`):

```
char* string = "I have a null terminator";
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does a char array initialized like so:
>
> `char foo[] = {0x31, 0x32, 0x33}; //123 
>   get a null terminator added to the end of it?

No, it will simply be an array of chars.

> Also is foo treated like a string literal by the compiler regardless of this method of initialization?

No, foo is not treated like a string literal. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).